# Protection Cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

That's my first pot here as I have some Idea about creating some Sheet paper on Google Sheets.

To be hones with all of you - Im not a programer and just creating something by using your knowladge on Stack and using Macros ( then changing scripts)

I have issue with authorization for blocked Cells.

The Idea : 
When our person that will be Confirming the Checkbox to TRUE Value, then I have a timestamp to be set with a note that is Stamped. After this process I want to have the cells locked by Script for that user that is editing sheet values(ChcekBox), but the main issue is that when Im on the Account I can't by script LockMyself from the Editing.

SO my question is : Is there any chance to call for Admin Account to lock that ?

Code:

```
 if (driverconfirm == "true")
    {

        spreadsheet.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
        stampedDriver.setValue('stamped')

        // - Lock Range
        var protection = spreadsheet.getRange('G57:J57').protect();
         protection.removeEditors([dem]);  // here is the issue as im on my account, and can't get rid off myself - DEM is the email address as Var
    };
```

Comment: This isn't possible. Only the owner can protect a range from an editor and an owner script can't be run by anyone else while retaining owner permissions. It's also not possible to retrieve the editor email address from an installable onEdit trigger from the owner account.

Comment: Ahhh... I found some other solution by setting up trigger onChange...and run all the time as its admin account doing that trigger and locking specific cells when tester is on sheet... But its working like on edit... And im worry about the times on each change... That I will reach 6hours of tasks and google will stop processing scripts, as I have at least 50 copies of that file running.